# Core Plot 2.3 download

Tags: download, core-plot

Where can I download CorePlot 2.3 version? There are a lot of threads talking about 2.3 version of CorePlot since last year but I cannot find it for downloading. I´m using Xcode 9.1 (9B55) and I need Core Plot 2.3 because previous versions of CorePlot give me errors when compiling the project.

The highest released version I found is 2.2 here https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/releases

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite finished, so you'll have to get it from the `release-2.3` branch and build it yourself. That's easy using CocoaPods.